# Python File-Watcher & Extract data from JSON to XLSX in a loop

Tags: python, json, loops, file-watcher

Hey guys can anyone help me debug this code please? I am stuck...

My Goal: To create a a loop that constantly checks a folder, to see if new .json files have been added every 60 second, then get some data from the newly added .json files, and export it to a xlsx.

I tried the code, no error comes up, but no output.xlsx is out either.

Here is the code

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join, splitext
import json
import pandas as pd
import time

# Define a function to return JSON files in a directory
def jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir: str):
    onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(my_dir) if isfile(join(my_dir, f)) and splitext(f)[1].lower() == '.json']
    return onlyfiles

# Function comparing two lists
def listComparison(originalList: list, newList: list):
    differencesList = [x for x in newList if x not in originalList]  # Note: if files get deleted, this will not highlight them
    return differencesList

def doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff: list, my_dir: str):
    for file_name in fileDiff:
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            json_data = json.load(file)

        # Extract data from JSON
        url = json_data["finalUrl"]
        fetch_time = json_data["fetchTime"]
        fcp_metric = json_data["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["id"]
        fcp_value = json_data["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
        fcp_score = json_data["audits"]["first-contentful-paint"]["score"]
        lcp_metric = json_data["audits"]["largest-contentful-paint"]["id"]
        lcp_value = json_data["audits"]["largest-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
        lcp_score = json_data["audits"]["largest-contentful-paint"]["score"]
        fmp_metric = json_data["audits"]["first-meaningful-paint"]["id"]
        fmp_value = json_data["audits"]["first-meaningful-paint"]["displayValue"]
        fmp_score = json_data["audits"]["first-meaningful-paint"]["score"]
        si_metric = json_data["audits"]["speed-index"]["id"]
        si_value = json_data["audits"]["speed-index"]["displayValue"]
        si_score = json_data["audits"]["speed-index"]["score"]
        tbt_metric = json_data["audits"]["total-blocking-time"]["id"]
        tbt_value = json_data["audits"]["total-blocking-time"]["displayValue"]
        tbt_score = json_data["audits"]["total-blocking-time"]["score"]
        cls_metric = json_data["audits"]["cumulative-layout-shift"]["id"]
        cls_value = json_data["audits"]["cumulative-layout-shift"]["displayValue"]
        cls_score = json_data["audits"]["cumulative-layout-shift"]["score"]

        # Clean data
        cleaned_fcp_value = fcp_value.replace('\xa0s', '')
        cleaned_lcp_value = lcp_value.replace('\xa0s', '')
        cleaned_fmp_value = fmp_value.replace('\xa0s', '')
        cleaned_si_value = si_value.replace('\xa0s', '')
        cleaned_tbt_value = tbt_value.replace('\xa0ms', '')

        # Create data dictionary
        data_dict = {
            "fetch_time": [fetch_time] * 6,
            "url": [url] * 6,
            "metric": ["first_contentful_paint", "largest_contentful_paint", "first-meaningful-paint",
                       "speed-index", "total-blocking-time", "cumulative-layout-shift"],
            "value": [cleaned_fcp_value, cleaned_lcp_value, cleaned_fmp_value, cleaned_si_value,
                      cleaned_tbt_value, cls_value],
            "score": [fcp_score, lcp_score, fmp_score, si_score, tbt_score, cls_score]
        }

        df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

        # Export DataFrame to Excel
        excel_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'output.xlsx')
        if os.path.exists(excel_file_path):
            with pd.ExcelWriter(excel_file_path, engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
                df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, header=False,
                            startrow=writer.sheets['Sheet1'].max_row)
        else:
            df.to_excel(excel_file_path, index=False)

        print(f"DataFrame exported to {excel_file_path}")

def fileWatcher(my_dir: str, pollTime: int):
    while True:
        if 'watching' not in locals():  # Check if this is the first time the function has run
            previousFileList = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)
            watching = 1
            print('First Time')
            print(previousFileList)

        time.sleep(pollTime)

        newFileList = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)

        fileDiff = listComparison(previousFileList, newFileList)

        previousFileList = newFileList
        if len(fileDiff) == 0:
            continue
        doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff, my_dir)

my_dir = r"C:\Users\84948\Desktop\EC\Project\Test_Folder"
pollTime = 60

fileWatcher(my_dir, pollTime)
```

I tried pretty much all I could, I was expecting an output.xlsx to come out (I have tested each block of code individually and they worked fine, but when they come together something does not add up.

Comment: Does the program ever print `DataFrame exported to ...` ? Do you know whether the function `doThingsWithNewFiles()` has been called?

Comment: The code creates/appends the Excel file for new JSON files only, it'll skip any existing JSON files.

Comment: @NickODell apparently after this guy Mohit Goyal advise it does now for sure!

Comment: @MohitGoyal you sir are ingenious!

Comment: @Zero could you have a look at my updated code? I still have some issue with it :( it works now but not to the full extend I need it to be. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76684076/file-watcher-loop-improvement-needed-please-help-me-you-kind-people