# File watcher loop cannot continue where it left off when re-running the code

Tags: python, json, loops, append, file-watcher

I have create this File Watcher Loop, when I run the code, it scans a specific folder for .json files and append to an 'output.xls' file. Then the code continues to run in a loop, scanning new files in the folder, and repeat the process. This works just fine, however, when I stop the code (laptop turn-off, or something), new files are still being added to the folder, and then when I re-run the code, I cannot continue where I left off, I have to delete the output.xls file and start over again.

Is there a way for this to save the history of the files already appended when I stop the code, and continue adding files that have not been appended when I re-run the code?

```
import os
import glob
import json
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir: str):
    # Get a list of JSON files in the directory
    json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(my_dir, "*.json"))
    return json_files

def clean_value(value):
    # Clean up numeric values by removing unnecessary characters
    return float(value.replace('\xa0s', '').replace('\xa0ms', '').replace(',', ''))

def doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff: list, my_dir: str, workbook):
    for file_name in fileDiff:
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            try:
                json_data = json.load(file)

                # Extract data from the JSON file
                url = json_data["finalUrl"]
                fetch_time = json_data["fetchTime"]

                audits = json_data["audits"]
                fcp_metric = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["id"]
                fcp_value = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                fcp_score = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["score"]
                lcp_metric = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["id"]
                lcp_value = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                lcp_score = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["score"]
                fmp_metric = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["id"]
                fmp_value = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                fmp_score = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["score"]
                si_metric = audits["speed-index"]["id"]
                si_value = audits["speed-index"]["displayValue"]
                si_score = audits["speed-index"]["score"]
                tbt_metric = audits["total-blocking-time"]["id"]
                tbt_value = audits["total-blocking-time"]["displayValue"]
                tbt_score = audits["total-blocking-time"]["score"]
                cls_metric = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["id"]
                cls_value = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["displayValue"]
                cls_score = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["score"]

                categories = json_data["categories"]
                perf_metric = categories["performance"]["id"]
                perf_value = 0
                perf_score = categories["performance"]["score"]

                # Clean up values and format the fetch time
                cleaned_fcp_value = clean_value(fcp_value)
                cleaned_lcp_value = clean_value(lcp_value)
                cleaned_fmp_value = clean_value(fmp_value)
                cleaned_si_value = clean_value(si_value)
                cleaned_tbt_value = clean_value(tbt_value)
                datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(fetch_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                cleaned_fetch_time = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                # Create a data dictionary for the DataFrame
                data_dict = {
                    "fetch_time": [cleaned_fetch_time] * 7,
                    "url": [url] * 7,
                    "metric": ["performance","first_contentful_paint", "largest_contentful_paint",
                               "first-meaningful-paint", "speed-index", "total-blocking-time",
                               "cumulative-layout-shift"],
                    "value": [perf_value, cleaned_fcp_value, cleaned_lcp_value,
                              cleaned_fmp_value, cleaned_si_value, cleaned_tbt_value,
                              cls_value],
                    "score": [perf_score, fcp_score, lcp_score, fmp_score, si_score, tbt_score, cls_score]
                }

                df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

                # Append the DataFrame to the Excel file
                sheet_name = "Sheet1"
                if sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
                    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
                    startrow = sheet.max_row
                    for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=False):
                        sheet.append(row)
                else:
                    sheet = workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name)
                    for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
                        sheet.append(row)

                print(f"Data extracted from {file_name} and appended to the Excel file")

            except KeyError as e:
                print(f"KeyError occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"JSONDecodeError occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")

def fileWatcher(my_dir: str, pollTime: int):
    excel_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'output.xlsx')
    existingFiles = []

    # Check if the output file already exists
    if os.path.isfile(excel_file_path):
        try:
            workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
            existingFiles = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)
            # Process the existing JSON files and append data to the Excel file
            doThingsWithNewFiles(existingFiles, my_dir, workbook)
            print("Existing JSON files processed and data appended to the Excel file")
        except openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException:
            workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    else:
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

    # Check for new files at startup
    newFileList = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)
    fileDiff = listComparison(existingFiles, newFileList)
    existingFiles = newFileList

    if len(fileDiff) > 0:
        # Process the new files and append data to the Excel file
        doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff, my_dir, workbook)

        # Save the Excel file
        workbook.save(excel_file_path)
        print(f"DataFrame exported to {excel_file_path}")

    while True:
        time.sleep(pollTime)

        # Get the updated list of JSON files in the directory
        newFileList = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)

        # Find the difference between the previous and new file lists
        fileDiff = listComparison(existingFiles, newFileList)
        existingFiles = newFileList

        if len(fileDiff) > 0:
            # Process the new files and append data to the Excel file
            doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff, my_dir, workbook)

            # Save the Excel file
            workbook.save(excel_file_path)
            print(f"DataFrame exported to {excel_file_path}")


def listComparison(originalList: list, newList: list):
    # Compare two lists and return the differences
    differencesList = [x for x in newList if x not in originalList]
    return differencesList

my_dir = r"Z:"
pollTime = 60

fileWatcher(my_dir, pollTime)
```

Comment: You can create/update a file with each loop, to store the list of already scanned files, and read it every time when you start the code.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't use the obvious solution that has been proposed by others? Or, even better, simply read the file names already stored in the spreadsheet and add any files not already present.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I was struggling for a bit until I tried storing the list of scanned files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a text file that has the list of scanned files stored.

Updated your code, to read if exists and write the text file.

```
from datetime import datetime
import glob
import json
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
import os
import pandas as pd
import time


def jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir: str):
    # Get a list of JSON files in the directory
    json_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(my_dir, "*.json"))
    
    return json_files


def clean_value(value):
    # Clean up numeric values by removing unnecessary characters
    return float(value.replace('\xa0s', '').replace('\xa0ms', '').replace(',', ''))


def doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff: list, my_dir: str, workbook):
    for file_name in fileDiff:
        file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, file_name)
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            try:
                json_data = json.load(file)

                # Extract data from the JSON file
                url = json_data["finalUrl"]
                fetch_time = json_data["fetchTime"]

                audits = json_data["audits"]
                fcp_metric = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["id"]
                fcp_value = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                fcp_score = audits["first-contentful-paint"]["score"]
                lcp_metric = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["id"]
                lcp_value = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                lcp_score = audits["largest-contentful-paint"]["score"]
                fmp_metric = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["id"]
                fmp_value = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["displayValue"]
                fmp_score = audits["first-meaningful-paint"]["score"]
                si_metric = audits["speed-index"]["id"]
                si_value = audits["speed-index"]["displayValue"]
                si_score = audits["speed-index"]["score"]
                tbt_metric = audits["total-blocking-time"]["id"]
                tbt_value = audits["total-blocking-time"]["displayValue"]
                tbt_score = audits["total-blocking-time"]["score"]
                cls_metric = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["id"]
                cls_value = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["displayValue"]
                cls_score = audits["cumulative-layout-shift"]["score"]

                categories = json_data["categories"]
                perf_metric = categories["performance"]["id"]
                perf_value = 0
                perf_score = categories["performance"]["score"]

                # Clean up values and format the fetch time
                cleaned_fcp_value = clean_value(fcp_value)
                cleaned_lcp_value = clean_value(lcp_value)
                cleaned_fmp_value = clean_value(fmp_value)
                cleaned_si_value = clean_value(si_value)
                cleaned_tbt_value = clean_value(tbt_value)
                datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(fetch_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                cleaned_fetch_time = datetime_obj.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

                # Create a data dictionary for the DataFrame
                data_dict = {
                    "fetch_time": [cleaned_fetch_time] * 7,
                    "url": [url] * 7,
                    "metric": [
                        "performance",
                        "first_contentful_paint",
                        "largest_contentful_paint",
                        "first-meaningful-paint",
                        "speed-index",
                        "total-blocking-time",
                        "cumulative-layout-shift"
                    ],
                    "value": [
                        perf_value, 
                        cleaned_fcp_value, 
                        cleaned_lcp_value,
                        cleaned_fmp_value,
                        cleaned_si_value,
                        cleaned_tbt_value,
                        cls_value
                    ],
                    "score": [
                        perf_score, 
                        fcp_score, 
                        lcp_score, 
                        fmp_score, 
                        si_score, 
                        tbt_score, 
                        cls_score]
                }

                df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)

                # Append the DataFrame to the Excel file
                sheet_name = "Sheet1"
                if sheet_name in workbook.sheetnames:
                    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]

                else:
                    sheet = workbook.create_sheet(sheet_name)

                for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
                    sheet.append(row)

                print(f"Data extracted from {file_name} and appended to the Excel file")

            except KeyError as e:
                print(f"KeyError occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")
            
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"JSONDecodeError occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")
            
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred while processing file '{file_name}': {e}")


def fileWatcher(my_dir: str, pollTime: int):
    excel_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'output.xlsx')
    
    existingFiles = []
    if os.path.exists(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'scanned_files.txt')):
        with open('scanned_files.txt', 'a+') as f:
            existingFiles = f.read().split('\n')

    # Check if the output file already exists
    if os.path.isfile(excel_file_path):
        try:
            workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file_path)
    
        except openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException:
            workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()

    else:
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        
        
    # Process the existing JSON files and append data to the Excel file
    
    if not "Sheet1" in workbook.sheetnames:
        doThingsWithNewFiles(existingFiles, my_dir, workbook)
        print("Existing JSON files processed and data appended to the Excel file")
    
    # Check for new files at startup
    while True:
        time.sleep(pollTime)

        # Get the updated list of JSON files in the directory
        newFileList = jsonFilesInDirectory(my_dir)

        # Find the difference between the previous and new file lists
        fileDiff = listComparison(existingFiles, newFileList)
        existingFiles = newFileList

        if len(fileDiff) > 0:
            # Process the new files and append data to the Excel file
            doThingsWithNewFiles(fileDiff, my_dir, workbook)

            # Save the Excel file
            workbook.save(excel_file_path)
            print(f"DataFrame exported to {excel_file_path}")

        with open('scanned_files.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write('\n'.join(existingFiles))


def listComparison(originalList: list, newList: list):
    # Compare two lists and return the differences
    differencesList = [x for x in newList if x not in originalList]
    
    return differencesList


my_dir = r"Z:"
pollTime = 60

fileWatcher(my_dir, pollTime)
```

Couldn't test the code, let me know if there's any issue with this.

Comment: Hi bro! Thank you for the grand efforts. I tested the code you gave me and it did generate a scanned_files.txt in my directory which updates the name of the scanned file. However, there is still an issue with the output.xls file. Apparently, when I run the code again, it does not take into account the files that were added to the folder while I stop the code. I have had this issue before. I think overwriting the output.xls file must be causing some problems.

Comment: You mean, when you stop the code, the files which are uploaded during that time, are added to the text file, but not getting written to your Excel?

Comment: Allow me to elaborate. I am having two issues:

Issue-1: When I first run the code, everything works, an output.xls file is created and appended (0), and the list of scanned json files is saved to a separate .txt file. However, when I stop the code and new json files are added (1), when I run the code again, these files are not scanned and appended. I have to keep the code running and wait until new files are being added (2), then all the files from (1) and (2) are added (3). 

Issue-2: When (3) happens, all the data from (0) are appended again, causing the rows to be duplicated.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your grand effort. I tried again and the two issues still persist. So far the job still works, it just that when I start the code again, I have to wait until new files are added to the folder, then both the new files and the files added while I stop the code will be added. Also there is still the error: when I start the code again and new files are added, all the files are added one more time, causing the rows to be duplicated.

Comment: Updated the code again and tweaked the logic as well, please check again, you can ping me if you're still facing any issues with this.

Comment: Hey bro! Thank you so much for the help. I tried the code again today, and I think the issue still persist: basically everytime i start the code over again, all the files are scanned one more time, hence the duplicated rows. For the time being, I just drop the duplicated rows in the output.xlsx file :D I think that works for now haha

Answer (score 0):

The simplest idea: To get the list of files changed since your last update to the Excel file, use `os.path.getmtime` to get the time of the last change of the Excel file and of all the JSON files, and select those JSON files that are newer. Do this at startup if the Excel file exists, and process each of the selected JSON files as if they were detected by the watcher.

However this could introduce some ambiguity about the files that are processed very near the power loss. So instead, the more accurate idea: save the list of processed JSON files, whether inside the Excel file, or in a separate place (e.g. another file, or a database).

An even more refined idea is to use a database where you save the data keyed to the JSON file, using the database as the single source of truth, and generate the Excel file from the database as needed.

---

As an aside, overwriting the Excel file is a possible point of failure. A good practice to do in this situation is to write to a temporary file in the same directory, then perform `os.rename`, which will atomically replace the old file with the new one.

Comment: Wow, this is some next level stuff for me. Can you elaborate :( I am such a novice.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What exactly do you have trouble with?

Comment: I am facing a new issue:
 
1. When I first run the code, everything works, an output.xls file is created and appended (0), and the list of scanned json files is saved to a separate .txt file. However, when I stop the code and new json files are added (1), when I run the code again, these files are not scanned and appended. I have to keep the code running and wait until new files are being added (2), then all the files from (1) and (2) are added (3). 

2. When (3) happens, all the data from (0) are appended again, causing the rows to be duplicated.